# More concise solution using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to parse a string and return the fit number for a specific person.  For instance, I could enter `Paul` and my method should return `34`.

Currently, I am accomplishing this through the use of `String`'s `substring` methods (my string will always be formatted the same):

```
String s = "{name : John, id : '0', fit : '34' }, {name : Paul, id : '0', fit : '34' },{name : Will, id : '0', fit : '24' } ";
String mainGrouping = s.substring(s.indexOf("Paul"));
System.out.println("Main Grouping: "+ mainGrouping);
String subGrouping = mainGrouping.substring(0, mainGrouping.indexOf('}'));
System.out.println("Sub grouping: " + subGrouping);
String fitGrouping= subGrouping.substring(subGrouping.indexOf("fit"));
String finalAnswer = fitGrouping.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

System.out.println("final substring: " + finalAnswer);
```

I believe there is a simpler, more concise solution using just one regular expression. However, I am largely unfamiliar with that topic. Is my assumption correct? If so could you explain your regex solution?

Comment: off topic (my comment, not your question): that's not a valid json string (John should be in quotes, etc...), and you don't want to parse json with regex ;)

Comment: @stuXnet Where did he say it was supposed to be JSON?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat nowhere, that's why i wrote "off topic" on front of my comment. I just assumed it, because it looks a bit like json.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat seems like wrong json, specifically because looks a lot like JSON but the numeric elements are enclosed between qotes like `String`s while the real `String`s are stored with no quoting. The best option would be to use plain JSON and use a proper JSON library to read/process this rather than using regexes.

Comment: @stuXnet Oh, sorry. I thought you were saying the the question was off-topic because that isn't a valid JSON string.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat oh - no, that's not what i meant, no problem :)

Comment: You'd be better off doing a one time parse of the string, storing the name/value pairs into an array  (or hash type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\{name : John, [^\}]*?fit : '(\d+)'.*?\}
```

This regex pattern will match fit's value in the first group, if it's applied to your example string.

Just in case you want to parse JSON strings using this method: it won't work like that. You can't rely on the order of attributes within JSON, to begin with.

If you really want to parse JSON, use libraries as others have mentioned.
If your example string is legit and you just need to do this for excercise, the regex pattern (or a slightly modificated version) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the question, it looks like with a minor effort your input data can be converted to a [JSON string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example), and thus can be parsed using a JSON-parsing library, such as [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

In this case, your input String s should look like this:

`String s = "[{"name" : "John", "id" : 0, "fit" : 34 }, {"name" : "Paul", "id" : 0, "fit" : 34 }, {"name" : "Will", "id" : 0, "fit" : 24 }]";`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that every `name` has a `fit` associated with it, and that every name appears before its respective `fit`, something like this should work:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.compile("name: " + nameToFind + ", .*?fit:'(\d+)'").matcher(s);
String fit = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
```

If you are are going to need this done repeatedly, and, possibly, for different attributes, consider, parsing the while string into a map (of maps):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}").matcher(s);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\w+?): '?(\\w*?)'?");
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<>();
while(m.find()) {
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(m.group(1));
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while(m2.find()) { map.put(m2.group(1), m2.group(2)); }
    result.put(map.get("name"), map);
}
```

Now, to find the value of "fit" for "Paul", you can just do `result.get("Paul").get("fit")`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegexEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{name : John, id : '0', fit : '34' }, "
                + "{name : Paul, id : '0', fit : '34' },"
                + "{name : Will, id : '0', fit : '24' } ";
        String name="John";
        String age = getAge(s, name);
        System.out.println(age);


    }

    private static String getAge(String s, String name) {
        String age=null;
        Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("name : "+name+"(.*)\\d\\d");
        String[] arr = s.split("}");
        for (String str : arr) {
            Matcher matcher = namePattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d");
                String match=matcher.group();
                Matcher numMatcher = numPattern.matcher(match);
                if(numMatcher.find())
                age=numMatcher.group();
            }
        }
        return age;
    }
}
```